# Java String Split with Multiple characters

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split a Java string:

```
"[1,2,3,4,5]"
```

So I have an array that only has the integers

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Without the ", [ ]"

I tried

```
String[] test = x.split("(, )|(\\[\\)|(\\]\\)");
```

Which I found in another thread but it does not work properly.
It keeps an empty string in `test[0]`.

Comment: What does *'without the ",[ ]"'* mean? I thought you wanted an array.

Comment: Why not try to replace the [] first, then split?

Comment: without replacing :- https://regex101.com/r/nW2lD2/1

Comment: Yes i want an array but what i get back was "[1  2 3 4 5]

Answer (score 5):

The easiest approach in this case seems that it would be to just replace the square brace characters `[` and `]` (via a [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) or [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) call) and then perform your [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) function using :

```
// Replace the square braces and then split using a comma
String[] output = input.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
```

or :

```
// Replace the square braces and then split using a comma
String[] output = input.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "").split(",");
```

Comment: Oh, it can even be [`String[] test = x.substring(1, x.length()-1).split(",");`](https://ideone.com/CsaQDq)

Comment: You can also parse it as a JSON Array. Bit of an overkill to add a JSON parser to the classpath just for this, but if you already have one, might as well use it.

Comment: @Wiktor and @Andreas, Both solid options, I went with the `replace()` / `split()` approach as it seemed the easiest to read for OP's purposes and for questions aimed at those just getting started (which I think this qualifies), I think readability is key.

Comment: In term of performance, the first option is clearly the best as you don't use any regex this way